# how to get id of looped div into javascript

Tags: javascript, html

This is my HTML form's Div:

```
<div class="form-image">
   <table>
      <tr>
         {% for count in 1..10 %} 
         <td id="form-image">
            {{loop.index}}
            <label for="file"> <img src="/OLX/Views/images/photo.png" id="{{loop.index}}" ></label>
            <input type="file"  accept="image/*" name="image" id="file"  onchange="change({{loop.index}},event)" style="display: none;">
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="cover-image" value="">
         </td>
         {% if count == 5 %}
      </tr>
      <tr>
         {% endif %}
         {% endfor %}
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

This is My Javascript to show the uploaded image:

```
function change (index,event) {
        alert(index);
        var image = document.getElementById(''+index+'');
        alert(image);
        image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
        index = index+1;
        alert(index);
}
```

How can i get the value of {{loop.index}} as index in javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the event target attributes :

```js
change = (e) => {

    console.log(e.target.attributes.key.value)

}
```

```html
<input id="someId" key="yourIndex" onchange="change(event)">
```

In your case :

```
<input type="file"  accept="image/*" name="image" id="file" key="{{loop.index}}"
 onchange="change(event)" style="display: none;">

 function change (event) {
     var index = event.target.attributes.key.value
 }
```

**edit:**

remove id s of:

```
<td id="form-image">
<input type="file"  accept="image/*" name="image" id="file"  onchange="change({{loop.index}},event)" style="display: none;">
```

Comment: i was tried this but still it always shows index=1 in javascript     it should be 2  3  4......10  depands on click  on specific column

Comment: Any warnings, errors on your browser console saying dupplicate id s?

Comment: id in all lines iside loop repeating so you should get error

Comment: remove id attribute of those two lines and try again]

Comment: ye i am using id="file{{loop.index}}"